# bootstrap5 dropdown-menu class not working on safari old ipad

Tags: ipad, bootstrap-4, dropdown

I have read a few posting on a similar issue but that does not seem to solve my issue.

Dropdown-menu class works fine on all browsers on my mac but does not seem to work on ipad (reported from my 91-year old mother on quite an old ipad).  Unfortunately, I do not own an ipad, so I can not test.

I read about the href="#" missing (but IMO that does not apply here) as well as the popper.js missing but it is within bootstrap.js... so what is I am doing wrong or is there a work around?

You can see it in action on my website in the [portfolio](https://www.paulgodard.com/portfolio) section.

Here is the code I use on my website to display a list of portfolio in a dropdown menu:

```
<div class="row d-flex justify-content-left">
    <div class="search-box col-md-8 col-lg-7 col-xl-6">
        <form action="/portfolio">
            <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownSubNav" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        Portfolios & collections...
                    </button>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownSubNav">
                        <li>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="/portfolio?p=portfolio">PORTFOLIO</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="/portfolio?p=portfolio&amp;c=bestof"> • Best Of</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="/portfolio?p=portfolio&amp;c=utopia"> • Utopia</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="/portfolio?p=portfolio&amp;c=blackwhite"> • Black &amp; White</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="/portfolio?p=portfolio&amp;c=ethereal"> • Ethereal</a>
                        </li>
                   </div>
                </div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="s" value="">
                <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="submit">
                        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <button id="mainHeartButton" style="visibility:hidden; display:none;" class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" onclick="window.location.href='/portfolio?s=cookie'; return false;">
                    <img id="mainHeart" src="/public/assets/icons/heart0.png" class="icon20" title="spacer">
                </button>
            </div>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;        
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It works fine on my Safari

Bootstrap supports latest stable release as below

[Browser and devices supported](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/browsers-devices/)

https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist#readme

```
>= 0.5%
last 2 major versions not dead
Chrome >= 60
Firefox >= 60
Firefox ESR
iOS >= 12
Safari >= 12
not Explorer <= 11
```